# How to retain memory of shared variable within a class that can be called by other functions/classes within a particular run

Tags: python, class

Here's a minimal example of a Python class object that I have in my code:

```
import numpy as np

class doSomething():
    def __init__(self):
        self.saveArray = np.zeros((1,10)).reshape((1,10))

    def completeTask1(self, someArg1a):
        ...
        tempArray = np.zeros((1,10)).reshape((1,10))
        tempArray[0,0] = float(someResultFromTask1)
        self.saveArray = np.vstack((self.saveArray, tempArray))
        ...

    def completeTask2(self, someArg2a, someArg2b):
        ...
        tempArray = np.zeros((1,10)).reshape((1,10))
        tempArray[0,4] = float(someResultFromTask2)
        self.saveArray = np.vstack((self.saveArray, tempArray))
        ...
```

This Python class can called by other functions/classes multiple times throughout one particular run/session. When the class `doSomething` gets initialized by other functions/classes, `saveArray` will be reset. I want `saveArray` to retain all its data throughout the run (and maybe save this later externally after the run/session is over).

One thought I have is to pass a reset argument like this below, but if I do this, `saveArray` won't be initialized, and this will throw off errors.

```
import numpy as np

class doSomething():
    def __init__(self, reset):
        if reset == 1:
            self.saveArray = np.zeros((1,10)).reshape((1,10))
        else:
            print('Retaining previous values...')

    def completeTask1(self, someArg1a):
        ...
        tempArray = np.zeros((1,10)).reshape((1,10))
        tempArray[0,0] = float(someResultFromTask1)
        self.saveArray = np.vstack((self.saveArray, tempArray))
        ...

    def completeTask2(self, someArg2a, someArg2b):
        ...
        tempArray = np.zeros((1,10)).reshape((1,10))
        tempArray[0,4] = float(someResultFromTask2)
        self.saveArray = np.vstack((self.saveArray, tempArray))
        ...
```

What can I do here to re-write the class in such that `saveArray` retains its value throughout the entire run of the program that consists of multiple classes/functions that might call on `doSomething`? One of the objectives of `doSomething` in my code is to track the health of the rest of the tasks (or functions) and also keep record of when the task is completed (or the function is called) throughout the entire run.

Comment: Perhaps you want a class attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a static class attribute

```py
class A:
    attr_to_retain = None

    def __init__(self):
        if A.attr_to_retain is None:
            A.attr_to_retain = ["some value to retain"]
            print("Initialized A.attr_to_retain")
        else:
            print("A.attr_to_retain already initialized")


x = A()
y = A()
```

This will only initialize the `attr_to_retain` on the first time the class is initialized. Then subsequently the value will not be `None`, therefore it will not be reinitialized again.

Running above code snippet will produce the following, proving that it only initialized once.

```
Initialized A.attr_to_retain
A.attr_to_retain already initialized
```

Comment: You don't even need the `None` aproach you can just do `attr_to_retain = ["some value to retain"]` right off the start - `None` approach would be used if, for some reason, the class attribute initial value depends on the attributes passed in the init.

Comment: @AlbertoPoljak It seems that if you assign some value to attr_to_retain outside of the __init__ function, then you might get errors suggesting usage before assignment. In this case the stated solution by Thu Yein Tun worked perfectly.

Comment: @troymyname00 actually, what @AlbertoPoljak said is right. I assumed you need to make sure it only init once based on the value you passed to the `__init__()`. It is not wrong to set the value of `attr_to_retain` anywhere else other than `__init__()`.